# Not clear for users to which team he/she plays

Tags: android, team

I have an sport app, in which you can set the results of your football (soccer) matches. In one screen, you need to set whether you played for the home/away team, the match result, and the team names (being the team's name of your team mandatory, and the other, optional.)

I came up with this screen:

[image]

As you can see, there is a button toggle in which you select whether you played **home or away**, and then below, you set **the result**, and the **teams' names**, in order, first the home team, then the away team.

But, it is not clear for the users, here are some examples of scenarios that happen:
- Sometimes they ignore the toggle buttons, so, they properly set the teams' names and order, but maybe they played for the away team, but they don't set in the toggle button that they played for the away team. 
- Other times they set the toggle button, but they always put the team they played for in the 1st edit text.

So, I think that somehow I need to emphasise for what team you set you're playing. I have some ideas but maybe I can get some feedback:
- Use elevation on the image, so for example, if you set you played home, the home team's kit would have an elevation.
- Put the picture of the user next to the edit text you set you're playing for. So, you would see your picture before the home team's name, if you set that you played for the home team.

Any suggestion?

Comment: As I see it, the person updating the scores should be from neither of the teams but instead be a third-party referee/coach. Same with team names, adding teams should be a separate tasks & screen, and here you can have a drop-down to choose from existing teams or existing matches. Please reconsider the scope of your app.

Comment: The person updating the scores it's part of one of the teams, it's an app for users to register/track their matches.

Comment: Just to clarify, why do need to know whether the person updating this is playing for the home or away team? The objective on this screen is just to update the score, right?

Comment: That's a good question... It's just for the user itself, maybe he wants to check in his/her statistics whether he/she performs better home or away. So that's why I add that

Answer (score 2):

First you can make the group button with no team pre-selected and disallow users to move forward before selecting the team. You can also make the buttons more prominent, also include the team tee in the same group etc.

Comment: I did not use that approach because I wanted to reduce to the minimum the number of "clicks" the user needs to do to add a match, but maybe making it not selected by default and adding like an error message would help to make it clear.